# A problem from Italian Mathematical Olympiad 2017

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Problem: Mim has a deck of $52$ cards, stacked in a pile with their backs facing
up. Mim separates the small pile consisting of the seven cards on the top of the
deck, turns it upside down, and places it at the bottom of the deck. All cards are
again in one pile, but not all of them face down; the seven cards at the bottom
do, in fact, face up. Mim repeats this move until all cards have their backs facing
up again. In total, how many moves did Mim make?

I noted that $52=7(7)+3$ and tried to perform the same algorithm on $10$ cards which is also in $7k+3$ form. I manually found out that this will take $20$ moves to do so. My friend actually has the patience to do all the tabulations on $52$ to see that that it will take $52$ rounds in total. I don't actually know the solution to this problem and I did all I could. Please help me solve this.

Edit: Here, the whole 7-pile is flipped upside down. It is not done individually.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers

Comment: Focus on each individual card. Suppose that a card with its back facing up is the $k$th card from the top at the start. Can you write down precisely at what moves will this card have its back facing down, and when it will face up? Try this for a few values of $k$, make a conjecture. Then find when, for all $k$, the backs are facing down for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Hints towards a solution:

- 7 seems specially chosen to match with 52.

  - It's likely that $ 52 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ is very helpful.
- Try smaller cases

  - What combination of (pile size , deck size) should we try? $(2, 52), (6, 52), (7, 51)$ and $(7, 49)$ likely doesn't give us quickly helpful information to work through this. So what smaller case should we consider?
  - In line with the above observation, let's try $(7, 7+3 = 10$).
  - What are the individual moves? How many moves does it take to return to the original position?
  - How is $ 3 \pmod{7}$ useful here? Is it useful?

> $1111111111 \rightarrow 1110000000 \rightarrow 0001111000 \rightarrow  0000000111 \rightarrow  1111111111$

- Hence, do the $(7, 7\times 7 + 3 = 52)$ case

  - It should just be a small tweak to the above, if you understood it well.
- Now, do the more general case of $(p, d)$.

  - What happens with $(7, 51)$? $(6, 52)$?